# Find/Match variable filenames and move files to respective directory

Tags: bash, variables, find, filenames, mv

I've ***never*** come to SO asking "Do my homework" but I really don't know where to start with this one.

I have a load of documents which are dumped in a directory after being auto-signed using JSignPdf (`--output-directory` option seemingly has no ability to output to same as input):

```
/some/dir/Signed/PDF1_signed.pdf
/some/dir/Signed/PDF2_signed.pdf
/some/dir/Signed/PDF2_signed.pdf
```

I'd like to then find their source/unsigned counterparts:

```
/some/dir/with/docs/PDF1.pdf
/some/dir/where/is/PDF2.pdf
/some/dir/why/this/PDF3.pdf
```

...and move the signed PDFs into the respective directories.

I use the command, to find all the PDFs in the variety of directories:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'exec java -jar jsignpdf-1.4.3/JSignPdf.jar ... ' sh {} +
```

...and I've tried things like making `find` output a variable and then using IF THEN to match with no success. Would I need `find` output to be made into multiple variables? I'm so lost :(

I'd like to accomplish this in some shell, but if there are Perl junkies out there or anything else, I am more than happy for another *portable* solution.

I've tried to break it down, but still don't understand how to accomplish it...

- find files matching VarName without _signed
- move _signed file with matching name to the directory of found file

Thanks for any help/guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `while` loop to read each file found by `find` and move it to the correct place:

```
find /some/dir -name "*.pdf" ! -name "*_signed.pdf" -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r file
do
  f="${file##*/}"
  mv "/some/dir/Signed/${f%.*}_signed.pdf" "${file%/*}"
done
```

Comment: Your last revision worked just as well, thanks for the code and cleaning it up a bit!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem I've been working on. Since the path manipulation required to convert `/some/dir/where/is/PDF2.pdf` to `/some/dir/Signed/PDF2_signed.pdf` is fairly simple but more involved than can be done in a simple one-liner, I've been using `find` to locate the first set, and using a simple loop to process them one at a time. You did mention homework, so I'll try not to give you too much code.

```
find /dir/containing/unsigned -name '*.pdf' -print0 | while IFS= read -d path; do
    fetch_signed_version "$path"
done
```

where `fetch_signed_version` is a shell function you write that, given a path such as `/some/dir/where/is/PDF2.pdf`, extracts the directory (`/some/dir/where/is`), computes the signed PDF's name (`PDF2_signed.pdf`), then executes the necessary move (`mv /some/dir/Signed/$signed_pdf /some/dir/where/is`)

---

`fetch_signed_version` is actually pretty simple:

```
fetch_signed_version () {
   dir=${1%/*}
   fname=${1##*/}
   signed_name=${fname%.pdf}_signed.pdf
   mv "/some/dir/Signed/$signed_name" "$dir"
}
```

Comment: It's for work, not a school assignment (I just meant to show I felt bad pretty much asking "Do this for me"). I appreciate the help :D